# How to elevate a single card in a group of cards css

Tags: html, css

Hi I need help in my design, i want to elevate a card that would look it is taller than the others. I added box-shadow but in only shows behind all the cards.

[image]

this is my html code

```
<section id="returned-item">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card ticket-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <p>This is a sample long lkdsjflkds jlds jdsjlksjflkjflkdsjdsjflkdsjf dslk jds lkfjds lkfj flkds jflkds jfdslk fjds lkfjds lkf jflkds jflkdsjds lkfjdslkjslk</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <p>7:30 AM</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col"><i class="fa fa-check-circle ticket-status-icon"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is my css

```
#returned-item .container .card {
  box-shadow:0 8px 8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12) !important;
  transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  transition:background .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
```

I want to make it look like this

[image]

Comment: We really need more info, show the html and your css, that will give us a much better chance to answer.

Comment: You may need to scale the card, add a z-index superior and a box shadow. But I agree with Poul Bak. You should edit your question and add the code.

Comment: Right, I should have thought of that. I updated my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: OMG, z-index work like a charm!!! Thank you so much